# How can you install a package into a specific directory using Ansible?

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using win_package to install many MSI's and EXE's. I would like to be able to pass a directory as an argument so that they get installed in a particular folder.

Right now they are automatically getting installed in C:/Program Files but I would like them to be installed on a different drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the MSI/EXE being able to accept the install location as a public property/parameter. Most standard installers will accept one of `TARGETDIR=somepath` or `INSTALLDIR=somepath` - when using `win_package`, you'd pass those with the `arguments` module arg (see [win_package docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_package_module.html#options)), eg:

```
- win_package:
    path: c:\path\to\install.msi
    arguments: "INSTALLDIR=c:\custompath"
```